# How to be sure that an unknown number of map updates have been completed?

Tags: android, google-maps, callback

I am facing the problem that I need to update a map on the screen such that the all points from the route the user has taken is visible.

In the code below, I count the number of times I request a map update, but I noticed that sometimes the number of requests doesnt match the number of callbacks. So waiting for 'mapLoaded' to become 0 is not a good idea.

Therefore I have added a time limit of 10 seconds, but this is arbitrary and sometimes just not enough.
So, how can I know for sure that all map update has been completed?

```
private void adjustMapCompleteSO(LatLng from, LatLng to){//3.3.17 show all points for screenshot
    double x1=(from.latitude+to.latitude)/2;
    double x2=(from.longitude+to.longitude)/2;
    LatLng del=new LatLng(x1,x2);
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(del));

    mapLoaded=0;

    for(Polyline pol : allcrumbs){
        List<LatLng> points = pol.getPoints();
        for (LatLng point : points){

            LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
            builder.include(point);

            LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
            int padding = 40; // offset from edges of the map in pixels

            CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, padding);

            mapLoaded++;
            map.setOnMapLoadedCallback(new GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback() {
                public void onMapLoaded() {
                    mapLoaded--;
                }
            });

            map.moveCamera(cu);
        }
    }
    Date started = new Date();
    while (mapLoaded !=0 && new Date().getTime() - started.getTime() < 10000){
        try {//wait until map has loaded, but max 10 seconds
            Thread.sleep(500);//wait half a second before tyring again
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show all polylines on the map.

Create a builder

```
        LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
```

Iterate over all the points in the polylines sending them to lat long bounds builder.

```
for(Polyline pol : allcrumbs){
    List<LatLng> points = pol.getPoints();
    for (LatLng point : points){
        //   dude never initialize variables in a loop again
        //   its automatic fail for speed of execution.
        // String never = "Do this in a loop";
        // int padding = 40; // offset from edges of the map in pixels
        builder.include(point);
    }
 }
```

Now move the camera

```
LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
int padding = 40; // offset from edges of the map in pixels
CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, padding);
map.moveCamera(cu);
```

IDK what your doing in the maploaded callback so its not in the above code.

Tip:  populate latlngbounds.builder as you create the polylines the simply move the camera when your finished loading the polylines.

```
LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
int padding = 40; // offset from edges of the map in pixels
CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, padding);
map.moveCamera(cu);
```

Note: moving the camera along a route would be similar to your code but you would typically only update the camera when the camera is finished for each point.